# Defining Set of Set in OPL (or indexed set)

Tags: set, tuples, cplex, ampl, opl

I try to define set of set in OPL. The problem is:

1. I have several Computing Platforms, for example: {"DC1", "DC2", "MP1"}
2. Each Computing Platforms can have several configuration, for example: DC1 may have {"conf1", "conf3"}, DC2 may have {"conf1", "conf2", "conf3"} and MP1 may have {"conf1", "conf3"}
3. each Computing Platforms have several attributes like capacity (vcpu)
4. the set of set in AMPL, and the parameter could be easily written as the following:

```
set COMPPLATFORMS;
set CONFCP{COMPPLATFORMS}

param vcpu {d in COMPPLATFORMS, CONFCP[d]};
```

However, in OPL we do not have a straightforward way of declaring an indexed set. I notice that we could use either tuple or maybe some preprocessing. But now I am not sure how to declare the parameter "vcpu" for the indexed set?

I know that we could have an array of sets, or sets of array. But could we have a set of set?

Is there any example in OPL that follow the similar structure?
Thank  you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See sets of sets in the example [power sets](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/howtowithopl/blob/master/powerset.mod) in [how to with OPL](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-opl-alex-fleischer/)

```
{string} s={"A","B","C","D"};
    range r=1.. ftoi(pow(2,card(s)));
    {string} s2 [k in r] = {i | i in s: ((k div (ftoi(pow(2,(ord(s,i))))) mod 2) == 1)};

    execute
    {
     writeln(s2);
    }
```

Comment: Hi Alex! Thank you, I really appreciate your help! :-)